# GET OR POST when calling an endpoint that inserts/updates but only relies on a value from the url (REST)

Tags: api, rest

When calling an endpoint that is technically creating or updating in the back-end but only requires a single ID to do so

**For example:**

api/v1/members/1/checkin
api/v1/members/1/checkout

The backend technically only needs the ID from the URL and can do what it needs to do.

I am trying to determine whether I should be making this a GET request or a POST request where the client is responsible for sending a body such as to an endpoint such as: api/v1/members/1/checkin

{
"id": 1
}

I understand this is all preference, but I would like to follow REST standards if possible here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GET` is a 'safe' HTTP requests should not alter the server state, or have side effects.

`POST`. is more appropriate. If you are passing `{ "id": 1 }` as a body, then `PUT` can also make sense.